# Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon default boot to shell / command line / disable GUI

Tags: linux-mint

## What I Want

I want to run a box as (typically) a 'server' (no GUI) and occasionally with the GUI because some things are easier that way.  I'm working with Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon.  I want to boot to console and not start `mdm` but I want to be able to switch back, so solutions involving totally removing `mdm` won't work well for me.

## What I've Tried

For the default boot, I have edited `grub` (whole file below) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` and run `sudo update-grub` but `mdm` still started; then I tried to set `mdm` to manual with `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mdm.override` but `mdm` still started.

I can stop `mdm` manually with `sudo service mdm stop` which is close to what I want.

## What's Wrong With My Solution

My best solution has me boot, starting `mdm` as usual, and then I must stop `mdm` manually.  I want the machine to start normally from a `reboot` or power cycle except the GUI doesn't start at all (unless I tell it to, e.g. by editing `grub` or choosing a different option in the `grub` menu).  By 'start normally' I mean that services like `tomcat` start and I can still `rsh` to the machine and/or remote debug it.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'


GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"


# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console


# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480


# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true


# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"


# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl disable mdm
```

This doesn't actually 'disable' the service, it just prevents it from automatically starting.

Then if you want to go into your gui, you do

```
sudo systemctl start mdm
```

And if you want to boot to gui by default:

```
sudo systemctl enable mdm
```

For pre-[systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) systems, you'll want to delete the symlink for mdm in your /etc/rc* directories.

Comment: thank you, that fixed it completely.  I thought "Linux Mint 18" was enough; do I need to say "Linux Mint 18 **Sarah**"?

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked where you indicated the version.  Am glad it worked for you!

Comment: Linux Mint 19 / Cinnamon uses lightdm, so `sudo systemctl disable lightdm` does the trick.

Comment: re-enable by calling `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` if `sudo systemctl enable lightdm` fails.